# Using Rich field data to maintain formatting with Word Doc Mail Merge

Tags: html, ms-word, mailmerge, netsuite, richtext

I built a SOW template generator that replaces a Word Doc's Mail Merge fields with Rich Text (using html markup) content from associated database fields.  Everything works as intended but I'm running into a few issues trying to get the formatting to look right.

My two main issues were bullet points and word wrap on lists.

To get the bullet point style I need, Word actually uses an 'o' and specifies 'courier new' as the font.  I can't specify the font because word will always override with the doc styles.

Word doesn't seem to honor list items when it does the merge so once text hits the edge of the doc it starts from the far left of the doc rather than tabbed for the bullet.  The page source generated when word is converted to html has a specific style and ID for every list and level.  I tried using the inline styling equivalents to get the wrap effect but it did not work.

Anyone have advice on how to correctly style these elements so Word will honor the formatting?

Here is an example of my markup that retains formatting the best so far:

```
<p style="margin:0;">Here is a bunch of random text:</p>
<p style="margin:0 0 0 1in;">•&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Executive Summary</p>
    <p style="margin:0 0 0 1.75in;text-indent:-.25in;"><span style="font-family: Courier New; mso-fareast-font-family: Courier New;">o</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Here is a lot more random text and stuff.  Super fun.</p>
    <p style="margin:0 0 0 1.75in;text-indent:-.25in;"><span style="font-family: Courier New; mso-fareast-font-family: Courier New;">o</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;More superfluous stuff.  If I knew Latin I would do that instead.</p>
    <p style="margin:0 0 0 1.75in;text-indent:-.25in;"><span style="font-family: Courier New; mso-fareast-font-family: Courier New;">o</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Summarized steps of nonsense.</p>

<p style="margin:0 0 0 1in;">•&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stuff Description</p>
    <p style="margin:0 0 0 1.75in;text-indent:-.25in;"><span style="font-family: Courier New; mso-fareast-font-family: Courier New;">o</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Description of the stuff and how the stuff was suppose to  to meet the needs of the peoples in the places.</p>

<p style="margin:0 0 0 1in;">•&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Reporting and stuff</p>
    <p style="margin:0 0 0 1.75in;text-indent:-.25in;"><span style="font-family: Courier New; mso-fareast-font-family: Courier New;">o</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Description of blah blah etc and more stuff.  This is a lot of useless text.</p>

<p style="margin:0 0 0 1in;">•&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Scope of stuff and methodlogy of stuff</p>

<p style="margin:0 0 0 1in;">•&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Findings and Recommendations of stuff</p>
    <p style="margin:0 0 0 1.75in;text-indent:-.25in;"><span style="font-family: Courier New; mso-fareast-font-family: Courier New;">o</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Scoring stuff and making sure people got the right stuff for the stuff.  Keeping the stuff safe one day at a time.  yay.</p>

<p style="margin:0;">Appendices: I had enough of this stuff so I'm going to stop typing.</p>
```

Comment: How are you replacing the merge fields with HTML?  Are you working in Word, or programmatically manipulating a docx file?

Comment: I'm using Netsuite's built-in Word Letter Merge function.  Basically, you generate a data source with the Netsuite fields and use it to create your word template for the merge.  Then you run a merge operation, which I'm kicking off through a Netsuite API script (server side javascript).  The merge creates a word doc using the corresponding fields from Netsuite.

Comment: So basically you're relying on Netsuite to convert your HTML into something Word can display. Isn't this a Netsuite question then, more than anything else?

Comment: Netsuite isn't really converting anything.  It's just supplying the info for the data source.  Anything beyond that should be Word's doing.  Although I guess I should try doing a mail merge with a different source and the same content to verify if it is actually a Netsuite issue.

Comment: To understand what is going on, we'll need to see the word doc output of the Netsuite merge operation, before it has been open/saved in Word.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't distribute the actual doc.  Seeing if I can get a mockup that is close enough but the project is on hold for now.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try saving your document as an .html web page, then simply use that generated code? I got something like:

```
<p class=MsoNormal>Hello hello hello.</p>

<p class=MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst style='text-indent:-.25in;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'>
<![if !supportLists]><spanstyle='font-family:Symbol;mso-fareast-font-family:Symbol;mso-bidi-font-family:Symbol'>
<span style='mso-list:Ignore'>·<span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span></span>
<![endif]>Test</p>

<p class=MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle style='text-indent:-.25in;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'>
<![if !supportLists]><spanstyle='font-family:Symbol;mso-fareast-font-family:Symbol;mso-bidi-font-family:Symbol'>
<span style='mso-list:Ignore'>·<span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span></span>
<![endif]>Test</p>

<p class=MsoListParagraphCxSpLast style='text-indent:-.25in;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'>
<![if !supportLists]><spanstyle='font-family:Symbol;mso-fareast-font-family:Symbol;mso-bidi-font-family:Symbol'>
<span style='mso-list:Ignore'>·<span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span></span>
<![endif]>This is so much test that the line actually goes all the way to the right of the page and then wraps back around to the beginning of the bullet. Wow.</p>

<p class=MsoNormal>No more bullets.</p>
```

If this works, could you post more about your methodology here? Very interested!

Comment: The problem is that when you save word into html it adds about 3000 extra lines of formatting.  Each list has it's only class and styling (mso-list) etc.  In my experience, when you convert from word to html, formatting remains intact, but the reverse is not the case.  Word is much more picky about formatting and it takes certain liberties with the output.  The HTMLI have above is actually much much closer in look and feel than trying to actually replicate the Word->HTML output formatting.

Comment: Ugh, I tried quoting out bits of this to frame my reply, but SO is being picky. Basically, try cleaning up your Word styles and use just direct formatting to make your lists. Even if Word's formatting XML is sometimes overkill, you'll get the solution you need and it should remain fairly readable and editable. Just be a little careful  to ensure your lists are cleanly done, then delete the unnecessary XML in the output.